# How to execute function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I built a function and I am trying to execute it... but some errors are occurring

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Afisho_rankimin
(
    @emri_rest int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @rankimi int

    Select @rankimi = dbo.RESTORANTET.Rankimi
    From RESTORANTET
    Where dbo.RESTORANTET.ID_Rest = @emri_rest

    RETURN @rankimi
END
GO

SELECT dbo.Afisho_rankimin(5) AS Rankimi
GO
```

Comment: How about telling us the errors?

Comment: I strongly recommend you use a Table Valued Function rather than a scalar function. And three part column references have been deprecated, use table aliases instead

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The function is not being created. Try calling your function something else.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Afisho_rankimin1(@emri_rest int)
RETURNS int
AS
   BEGIN
       Declare @rankimi int
       Select @rankimi=dbo.RESTORANTET.Rankimi
       From RESTORANTET
       Where  dbo.RESTORANTET.ID_Rest=@emri_rest
       RETURN @rankimi
  END
  GO
  
  SELECT dbo.Afisho_rankimin1(5) AS Rankimi
```

Comment: Copy snippets are for JavaScript only... please stop using them on SQL.

Comment: Why would changing the name make any difference?